# How to get linux to recognize where R is located

Tags: r, linux

I am sure this is a trivial question, but I am trying to install multiple R versions in Linux. I am not using R studio server pro and am instead using the free R studio server. I followed this [documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R-on-Linux) to install R but got errors when I attempted to locate it. However, when I run a command to see what version of R is installed, there is no error.

### R is installed!

```
(base) noah@noah-VirtualBox:/opt/R/4.1.3$  /opt/R/4.1.3/bin/R --version
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

### Attempts

```
(base) noah@noah-VirtualBox:/opt/R/4.1.3$ R

Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install r-base-core
```

```
(base) noah@noah-VirtualBox:/opt/R/4.1.3$ which R
(base) noah@noah-VirtualBox:/opt/R/4.1.3$
```

### Steps to reproduce

```bash
export R_VERSION=4.1.3

curl -O https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-4/R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xzvf R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd R-${R_VERSION}
```

```bash
# Build and install R
./configure \
    --prefix=/opt/R/${R_VERSION} \
    --enable-memory-profiling \
    --enable-R-shlib \
    --with-blas \
    --with-lapack
```

```bash
make
sudo make install
```

```bash
# Verify R installation
/opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R --version
```

```bash
# Create a symlink to R
sudo ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R /usr/local/bin/R
sudo ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/Rscript /usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

```bash
# Export path so Rstudio can find it
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R='/opt/R/4.1.3/bin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it.  Just install in, say,

```
/opt/R/4.2.0/
/opt/R/4.1.2/
/opt/R/4.0.5/
```

and then either set the `$PATH` to the `bin/` directory in the version you want, or call `R` directly.  It is what pretty much exactly what many of us have done with two versions of R (i.e. R-release and R-devel):

```
$ R --version | head -1
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
$ 
$ /usr/lib/R/bin/R --version | head -1
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
$ 
$ /usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin/R --version | head -1
R Under development (unstable) (2022-05-24 r82398) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"
$
```

The first two are the same as that is my 'default' version. The third is my one alternate.  And that is all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am installing in /opt.  My issue is that when I try to call R from the terminal, it says it isn't installed, but when I ask for the version, it lists it

Comment: Apologies, I now see that running `/opt/R/4.1.3/bin/R` launches R from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `/usr/local/bin` to your $PATH variable you would have been able to launch R, if it was not already present.

You could add it to .bashrc in your home directory

```
echo "export path=\"${PATH}:/usr/local/bin\"" |tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

Links for installing R from package, Ubuntu / Debian, RHEL 9, RHEL 8, RHEL/CentOS7

https://docs.posit.co/resources/install-r/

Also see

**(Optional) Install multiple versions of R**, on the same page.